# Quick Running Time Question

Tags: asymptotics

I have a quick question about some running time stuff. In my algorithm I run merge sort twice, then loop $n$ times. If this is the case, does this make sense?

$\Theta(nlogn+nlogn+n) = \Theta(nlogn)$.

I am a bit uncertain about the $\Theta(nlogn+n) = \Theta(nlogn)$ aspect but fairly certain this is a true statement.

Edit : Should add that only constant operations occur within the loop.

Comment: You are correct. To see why $n\log{n}\gt n$ take $n$ large enough so that $\log{n}\gt 1$.

Comment: Thought so, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's true. Since $n \log{n} > n$, complexity grows (is dominated by) $n \log{n}$.

Comment: Thought so, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Upper bound:
$$
f(n)=n \log n +n \log n +n  \leq 3  n \log n= O(n \log n)
$$
Lower bound:
$$
f(n) \geq 2 n \log n =\Omega (n \log n)
$$
hence $f(n)=\Theta(n \log n)$